# ¿Cuál es el número máximo de etiquetas que puedes modificar?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, ediciones-sugeridas

He estado revisando algunas etiquetas y aplicando descripción a algunas de ellas que no tenían. Cuando llevaba 3 etiquetas modificadas, en las siguientes etiquetas que entraba a modificar ya no me dejaba, no me aparecían los cuadros para poder poner alguna descripción.

¿Hay algún límite diario o algo parecido de edición de etiquetas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/289691) a [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/289691) hay un límite de 5 ediciones sugeridas pendientes para usuarios con < 2k de reputación. Una vez que una edición sugerida sea aprobada podrás realizar otra.